# Is there a polynomial of degree at most 99 whose values at 1, 2,... , 1000 alternate between 0 and 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

This is a question from [Problem set 2 of MIT’s 18.700 Linear algebra course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-700-linear-algebra-fall-2013/0c06d39b6060e86b711be1c3b1f0a224_MIT18_700F13_ps2.pdf).

We have the following setup. $V$ is a vector space of real polynomials with degree at most $99$. Also, $T:V\to \mathbb{R}^{1000}$ is a linear map such that

$$ T(p) = (p(1), \dots, p(1000)) $$

**Part (a)** asks you what $\dim\ker T$ is. I thought the only possible polynomial $p$ with $\deg p \leq 99$ such that $p(1)=\dots=p(1000)=0$ is the zero polynomial (i.e. $p=0$). The reason is because [the factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) tells you if $p$ is a polynomial for which $p(1)=\dots=p(1000)$, it must have $(x-1), \dots, (x-1000)$ as its factors. So, $\deg p \geq1000$, which is contradictory to the assumption that $\deg p \leq 99$. Therefore, $\dim\ker T = 0$.

**Part (b)** asks you what $\dim \text{range }T$ is. I used the theorem $\dim V = \dim\ker T + \dim \text{range }T$ for linear maps, and concluded $\dim \text{range }T = 100$ ($\because \dim V = 100)$.

**Part (c)** is where I got stuck. It asks whether the vector $(0,1,0,1,\dots,0,1)$ is in the range of $T$. I have one solution in mind, but it seems like it’s completely irrelevant to linear algebra, which makes me think this is not the solution that the instructor intended.

My argument went similarly as in part (a). If there is a polynomial $p$ with $\deg p \leq 99$ such that $T(p) = (0, 1, 0, 1, \dots, 0, 1)$, it means that $p$ has at least $500$ roots ($x\in\{1, 3, 5, \dots, 999\}$), which implies $\deg p \geq 500$ (by the factor theorem), which again is a contradiction.

I think my question can be phrased as: Can you deduce $(0,1,0,1,\dots,0,1)\notin \text{range }T$ just from the fact that (without referring to the factor theorem)

1. $T:V\to \mathbb{R}^{1000}$ is a linear map
2. $\dim V = 100$
3. $\dim \ker T = 0$
4. $\dim \text{range } T = 100$

I think there should be some more linear algebra-style of proof. I’d appreciate any comment or help! Thank you.

Comment: I think your professor is trying to get you to understand an example where you translate facts from outside linear algebra to linear algebra language. This is a good thing to do, +1 to your professor! As often happens in mathematics, having a different language can illuminate the nature of a proof, but there's still a remaining nugget of "math" that's irreducible.

Comment: How much linear algebra are you allowed to use, given that this is problem set 2?

Comment: Could 1000 be a mistake? The problem looks like it would be more interesting with 100 in place of it.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni If you look at the problem set, the problem with 100 was the prior one, so it's unlikely to be a mistake.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni That suggests that "https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/3622888.pdfNo." MAY be the answer.

Comment: It seems like 99 and 999 are switched in the two problems, no?

Comment: @JeremyWeissmann Then there would be two essentially identical problems in the set; that seems unlikely.

Comment: Are problems 1 and 2 essentially different in some way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a linear algebra-style (i.e. dimension-counting) proof, to show that a specific element is not in the range of a specific map. If your map was

$$T(p) = (p(1), 0, p(3)/3, 0, p(5)/5), \dots ) $$

then $T$ would satisfies all the same properties, but $(1,0,1, \dots) = T(x \mapsto x)$ would be in the range of $T$. So your proof must necessarily rely on the specific properties of the mapping $T$.

But your proof is fully correct and probably the most simple proof one could come up with.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that's coded in linear algebra-speak, but it might be a tad too advanced for Problem set 2.

Define a linear function $D:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ as $D(p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_{n} ) = ( p_2 - p_1, p_3 - p_2, \ldots, p_n-p_{n-1})$.

Prove the following:

- The kernel of $D$ has dimension 1, corresponding to $(1, 1, 1, \ldots , 1)$.
- Since $(1, 1, 1\ldots, 1) \in T(p)$, hence the dimension of $D(T(p))$ is 99.
- Show that for $k \geq 1$, $D^{k+1}  (1^{\underline{k}}, 2^{\underline{k}}, 3^{\underline{k}}, \ldots ) = 0 $, where $i^{\underline{k} } = i(i-1)(i-2) \ldots (i-k+1)$.
- The dimension of $D^{100} ( T(p) )$ is 0.
- $D^{100} ( 0, 1, 0, 1, \ldots, 0, 1 ) \neq 0 $.
- Hence, $( 0, 1, 0, 1, \ldots, 0, 1 ) \not \in T(p)$.

Answer (score 3):

P(x) - 1/2 has 999 zeroes between 1 and 1000 and therefore has no degree lower than 999; same for p(x).

No idea how you would use linear algebra to prove this.

You could use a similar proof if the polynomial has values 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4 etc. because then p(x) - x/2 would behave exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can't prove it just using 1-4, since there is a linear map satisfying 1-4 with image any given 100-dimensional subspace (choose ordered bases of $V$ and your target subspace, and use this to determine a linear map in the obvious way). Even if you could, it's not clear what the point would be since you would still need the factor theorem to show this map satisfies 1-4 in the first place.